# Trimming NTFS and ext4 Formatted SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, ubuntu-14.04, trim

I have a Kingston SSDNOW V300 120 GB SSD with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the 32GB ext4 partition. When I issue the command **fstrim -v /**, it responds, **30998127689 trimmed**.

My computer detects it as two drives. The first drive has two partitions: **ext4** and **NTFS**. The second drive is formatted as **NTFS**.

My question is, can I **trim the whole SSD drive**, not just the **ext4** partition? If so, then how?

Answer (score 7):

TRIM is a file system level operation and must be supported for each file system you are using.  The ext4 driver supports the `fstrim` command under Ubuntu 14.04 but the NTFS driver does not. You need a newer version of NTFS-3G; Ubuntu 14.04 ships with [NTFS-3G 2013.1.13](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ntfs-3g); the support for the `fstrim` command was added in [NTFS-3G 2015.3.14](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ntfs-3g.devel/1101). Your easiest option is to wait for Ubuntu 16.04 which will ship with NTFS-3G 2015.3.14.

Comment: I don't think ntfs-3g (or any FUSE driver) supports the FITRIM ioctl.

Comment: "Implemented FITRIM (fstrim) ioctl" is mentioned in the [announcement for NTFS-3G 2015.3.14](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ntfs-3g.devel/1101). The link was in my answer, you only need to open it.

Comment: Good to know. I will undo my downvote if you edit your answer (e.g. changing `the TRIM command was added` to `the support for fstrim was added` would be nice anyway).

Comment: Thanks for seeing my point. Now you can even upvote my corrected answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, `trim` is a filesystem operation, it needs to know what sectors are free so it can inform the hardware. The Linux ntfs-3g driver has no [documented calls](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) for `trim` or `discard` so it will not work. You will need to `trim` or `discard` each filesystem in it's native OS.

Don't worry too much about it though, your SSD drive will happily chug along forever without trim, it is not a requirement and your drive will work fine. [Here](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/04/ask-ars-my-ssd-does-garbage-collection-so-i-dont-need-trim-right/) is an explanation of what TRIM *really* does

Comment: `TRIM` is an ATA command (or precisely, a "bit" in the `Data Set Management` ATA command). `discard` is pretty much a general term in Linux for TRIM/UNMAP (something like `deletenotify` in Windows).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to TRIM a whole block device (partition/disk), you can use `blkdiscard`, which is available in `util-linux` as `fstrim` is.

However, this kind of TRIM is basically equivalent to wiping all the data on the device, since it's not filesystem-aware.

You may want to look into `wiper.sh` in `hdparm` if you really want to TRIM the NTFS partition. AFAIK it is filesystem-aware but does not rely on the FITRIM (or BLKDISCARD) ioctl in the kernel, instead it checks which blocks are unused using filesystem-specific utilities (hence it requires `ntfs-3g` for NTFS), and then perform TRIM on them with SCSI ATA PASSTHROUGH commands.